# CSS - jpg image repeating

Tags: html, css

I am re-writing a website and i have inserted a background. 
The background image is repeating. 
I've tried various ways on setting the repeat = n without any luck.

Here is the current html section:

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
    <title>Site down | Maintenance</title>
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <style type='text/css'>
        html,
        body {
            padding: 0;
            border: 0
        }

        .Header_image {
            padding- left: 20px
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: "verdana";
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            font- size: 16pt;
            color: #D5261e
        }

        h3 {
            font-family: "verdana";
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 1px;
            font-size: 11pt;
        }

        p {
            font-family: "verdana";
            font-size: 13;
        }

        div.wide_rhn {
            padding-bottom: 17px
        }

        div.pg_three_col_border {
            BORDER-right: #e8e8e8 1px solid;
            BORDER-left: #e8e8e8 1px solid;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            PADDING-TOP: 11px;
            PADDING- LEFT: 17px;
            padding-bottom: 11px;
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 75%;
            width: 763px;
            ^width: 782px
        }

        table.HP_table_header {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 200;
            padding- bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            *padding-bottom: 12px
        }

        td.HP_mainmenu {
            border: #878787 1px solid
        }

        table.HP_Image_table {
            MARGIN-LEFT: 124px;
            MARGIN-TOP: 1000px
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body background="man-with-no-shoes.jpg">

    <table class='HP_table_header' width='960' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class='Header_image' width='189' align='left' height='74'>
                    <img src='images/test_logo.jpg' border='0' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class='bg_body' width='1006' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='height: 500px;'>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign='top'>
                    <table width='960' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign='top' width='782' align='left'>
                                    <div id='WiderhPagetitlemain'>
```

Comment: Please start by making your code readable

Comment: Problems with your code: 1. Your CSS style attributes have space between them (i.e padding- top and so on). 2. Format your code properly and close all the container tags you have opened. 3. As the others have mentioned, use the CSS property of background-repeat: no-repeat; on your body CSS selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using background-repeat:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

You can then use:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

If you have your background on body, you simply do:

```
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

That means - in your code in `<style type='text/css'>` you simply add following:

```
    body {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

---

Also, please note it is usually better to set your background image in CSS rather than in HTML as you have better separation of concerns:

- Html is responsible for content and structure
- Css is responsible for visuals

You can set background image in CSS using [background-image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) property:

```
body {
   background-image: url("background.jpg");
}
```

---

Having said that, it is also a good idea to move your CSS to a separate file rather than having everything in your HTML - again, the separation is better.

You can then link your new file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my-new-stylesheet.css">
```

Comment: Tries the no-repat it fails to sort it, could it be something in the CSS?

Comment: I updated my answer, to show what exactly you need to add.

Answer (score 0):

```
.someCssSelector{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Add your background using css.And then set attribute to no-repeat.

Comment: body { background: url('man-with-no-shoes.jpg') center center no-repeat);background-size: cover;

Answer (score 0):

Here you go buddy:

```
    <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
    <title>Site down | Maintenance</title>
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <style type='text/css'>html,body {padding:0;border:0}.Header_image {padding-
    left:20px}
    h1 {font-family:"verdana" ; padding:0px;margin:0px;font-
    size:16pt;color:#D5261e}
    h3 {font-family:"verdana" ; padding:0px;margin:1px;font-size:11pt;}
    p {font-family:"verdana" ; font-size:13;}
    div.wide_rhn {padding-bottom:17px}
    div.pg_three_col_border {BORDER-right: #e8e8e8 1px solid;BORDER-left: 
    #e8e8e8 1px solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;PADDING-TOP:11px;PADDING-
    LEFT:17px;padding-bottom:11px;font-family:arial;font-size:75%;width: 
    763px;^width: 782px}
    table.HP_table_header {position:relative;z-index:200;padding-
    bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;*padding-bottom:12px}
    td.HP_mainmenu {border:#878787 1px solid}
    table.HP_Image_table {MARGIN-LEFT:124px;MARGIN-TOP:1000px}





body {
    background-image: url(man-with-no-shoes.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    </style>



    </head>
    <body>

    <table class='HP_table_header' width='960' align='center' border='0' 
    cellpadding='0'cellspacing='0'>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class='Header_image' width='189' align='left' height='74'><img 
    src='images/test_logo.jpg' border='0' /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class='bg_body' width='1006' align='center' border='0' 
    cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'style='height: 500px;'>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td valign='top'>
    <table width='960' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' 
    cellspacing='0'>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td valign='top' width='782' align='left'>
    <div id='WiderhPagetitlemain'>
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried the 'user3142783' and image doesn't show up just the content.

Comment: Where is the image file kept and what is the name of the image?